# How set checked on div elements in ExtJS using JavaScript-Console

Tags: javascript, extjs

`<div class="x-grid-row-checker">&nbsp;</div>`

How to set all checkbox **checked** by using JavaScript-Console?
**Jquery is not available.**

that's the source of the complete page: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/sl5net/ae2503ec7bb098ce0cfb7456aeca806d/raw/7b74a324aa90fad33b2d75efc1a3fa0ee7e5459b/backend18-09-13_11-48

I hoped something similar would be possible like:

`javascript:[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('x-grid-row-checker'),function(el){el.checked=true});`

Screenshot of the checkboxes:

[image: 3 checkboxes]

Comment: Provide your source code

Comment: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/sl5net/ae2503ec7bb098ce0cfb7456aeca806d/raw/7b74a324aa90fad33b2d75efc1a3fa0ee7e5459b/backend18-09-13_11-48 i will add it also into the question

Comment: It depends what you're trying to do. Are you actually trying to make the boxes select as far as the grid is concerned? Or just visually?

Comment: Yes my idea was really to make the boxes checked. Not just visually. Is that not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is a single grid on the page:

```
const node = document.querySelector('.x-grid');
const grid = Ext.getCmp(node.id);
grid.getSelectionModel().selectAll();
```

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ldf).

Comment: Works in ShopWare articele Overview 
 https://imgur.com/a/SYA9vjs Works . And not (as you already said) by using three grids. Next i need to check the right goup of checkboxes here:  https://imgur.com/a/LbMG4SS